# how is dropbox desktop application programmed?

Tags: windows, desktop-application, dropbox

I wanted to know in what language has the desktop application of Dropbox been coded? 
Is it Python or Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is python notice the Python25.dll file in the bin folder next to the exe

Comment: +1 Interesting. And the Mac version also includes Python stuff.

Comment: @Thilo nice to know, probably most of the stuff is the same then for all OS's

Comment: Thanks for the replies :)
And does the web-app also work on python itself ?

Comment: @user1495471 Python as well, except for the forums :) which are powered by a third party PHP framework

Answer (score 2):

99.9 % of their code is in Python. Used on the server backend; desktop client, website controller logic, API backend, and analytics. Not on Android due to memory constraints. Runs on a single code base using Python. Dropbox runs on Windows, Mac, Linux using tools like PyObjs, WxPython, types, py2exe, py2app, PyWin32.

Source: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/14/6-lessons-from-dropbox-one-million-files-saved-every-15-minu.html

Comment: "Not on Android due to memory constraints." Also not on iOS, I guess.